# UWP Launch file error 'the remote procedure call failed'

Tags: c#, windows-10, win-universal-app

I'm writing an player for UWP by C#.

I have an issue with launching file.

When app is open, launching files works very well but when I close the app and launch a file, it gives me error:
'the remote procedure call failed'

I set fileTypeAssociation, and here some of my code for launching in App.xaml.cs:

```
protected override void OnFileActivated(FileActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame rootFrame = CreateRootFrame();
    if (rootFrame.Content == null)
    {
        if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e))
            throw new Exception("Failed to create initial page");
    }
    else
        rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(PlayerPage), e);
    Window.Current.Activate();
}
```

how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> error 'the remote procedure call failed'

This crash happens usually in app launching, activating or page loading stage.

Since your app works fine when launch files during the app is open, I just assume that your code in the `OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)` method works fine.

And you didn't post your code of `CreateRootFrame()`, I can't really reproduce your problem according your posted code. I changed your code like this and it works fine by my side:

```
protected override void OnFileActivated(FileActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    //base.OnFileActivated(args);
    var rootFrame = new Frame();
    rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(PlayerPage), args);
    Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
    Window.Current.Activate();
}
```

It's quite simple that you just need to navigate to your player page in the `rootFrame`.

I wrote a very simple demo [LaunchAppFromFile](https://github.com/GraceFeng/LaunchAppFromFile) here, you can test it. Just download and run it then close this app, choose a .mp4 or a .wmv file and open with this app, it will navigate to the `PlayerPage` and play the file.

Maybe you can share your code of `CreateRootFrame()` method, or tell me what else you need to do when launch app from file, I'll keep tracking this problem.

Comment: Thanks for reply. your codes works very well. looks like CreateRootFrame couldn't create a frame. thanks alot